# Regular expression using sed in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I want to replace variable using sed .To replace i need to know what is present in a file ,So i want to extract that string using regular expression .

```
$ cat file1.txt
select * from ${database_name}.tab_name;
```

I want to take `${type_database_name_env}` into a string and use sed replace command to replace that variable with actual name

```
sed -n 's/[${][a-z][_][a-z][_][a-z][_][a-z][}]/,/./p' file1.txt
```

I need output as

```
$ var1=`sed command` # I am looking for proper sed command
$ echo $var1
${database_name}
```

Comment: Try `var1="$(sed -En 's/.*(\$\{[^{}]*}).*/\1/p' file"`, see https://ideone.com/lsgsnw

Comment: Thanks for quick response it worked !

Comment: I had used grep command it worked fine . file_data=`echo $file`;val1=`echo $file_data | grep -o '${.*}'`

Comment: I added `grep` solution to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `grep`, you may use

```
var1="$(grep -o '\${[^{}]*}' file1.txt | head -1)"
```

The `| head -1` is used to exract the first match in case there are more.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/Pd1hxF):

```
f='select * from ${database_name}.tab_name;'
var1="$(grep -o '\${[^{}]*}' <<< "$f" | head -1)"
echo "$var1"
```

With `sed`, you may use

```
var1="$(sed -En 's/.*(\$\{[^{}]*}).*/\1/p' file"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/lsgsnw):

```
f='select * from ${database_name}.tab_name;'
var1="$(sed -En 's/.*(\$\{[^{}]*}).*/\1/p' <<< $f)"
echo "$var1"
# => ${database_name}
```

**Regex details**

- `.*` - matches 0+ chars
- `(\$\{[^{}]*})` - captures into Group 1 (`\1`) a `$` char followed with `{`, 0+ chars other than `{` and `}` and then a `}`
- `.*` - matches 0+ chars.

As the replacement is the reference to the Group 1 text, it is all there remains after `sed` does its job. Note the `-E` option: it enables the POSIX ERE syntax where `(...)` are used to specify a capturing group, not `\(...\)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use awk:

```
$ awk -F'[ .]+' '{print $4}' file
${database_name}
```